# bulletproof width hack in css that will cover all including Safari?

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, safari

I've been using this class to properly stretch divs and inputs to fit the available space, without overflowing because of padding, like `-moz-available` does.

It's working in Firefox, Chrome, Opera.

Unfortunately, Safari seems to be the only browser that won't get along with it.

```
.width {
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
width: -moz-available;
width: -webkit-fill-available;
}
```

Is there anything I can add onto this to make it work with Safari?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The width: 100% declaration works just fine in Safari (and in other browsers).  The difference between the width: 100% and width: available declarations is that the former should be used with box-sizing: border-box to prevent overflows and the latter can be used without box-sizing: border-box declaration.  Thus, your class can be rewritten as follows and it should work in Safari:

```
.width {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box: 
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Hah, I feel dumb right now. I've been using border-box for so long just out of habit, that I forgot its actual purpose in preventing broken box-size warnings. Thank you for the reminder.